# Звонок на телефон python

Tags: python

Кто знает как позвонить на телефон при помощи python?
Желательно что бы в конце была просто функция
call(79277880405):

Comment: Глянь bulksms api

Answer (score 2):

Вы должны понимать, что должны использовать какой-то сервис\шлюз\АТС в качестве исходящего абонента.

Например Twilio [исходящие](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-python), [входящие](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/make-receive-phone-calls-python-bottle-twilio-voice.html)

пример исходящего звонка через Twilio:

```
# Загрузите вспомогательную библиотеку https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install

from twilio.rest import Client

# Ваш аккаунт Sid и Auth Token из twilio.com/console
account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
                         twiml='<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>',
                         to='+14155551212',
                         from_='+15017122661')

print(call.sid)
```

`twiml` - язык разметки Twilio, который просто говорит о том, что это XML- документ со специальными тегами, определенными Twilio, чтобы помочь вам создавать ваши SMS и голосовые приложения.

Comment: Желательно добавить минимальный пример, хотя бы тот что по первой ссылке.

Comment: добавлен пример