# Телеграм бот на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

Хочу создать телеграм бота, который будет звонить на заданный номер в определенное время. Подскажите как осуществить звонок? В какую сторону нужно смотреть, про что читать?

Comment: Здраствуйте! Попробуйте почитать здесь https://m.habr.com/ru/post/262247/ и здесь https://khashtamov.com/ru/create-telegram-bot-in-python/

Comment: Приведите информацию по ссылкам в самом ответе, чтобы при инвалидации ссылок ответ сохранил смысл

Comment: Как создать бота я знаю, хотелось бы узнать как осуществлять звонки на телефон через бот

Comment: Звонить  на телефон с помощью бота нельзя, можно только отправить голосовое сообщение или аудио.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/523033)

Comment: Никак. Возможности совершать звонки в Bot API нет. Как и нет возможности узнать идентификатор чата по номеру телефона(это конфиденциальная информация).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны понимать, что должны использовать какой-то сервис\шлюз\АТС в качестве исходящего абонента.

Например Twilio [исходящие](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-python), [входящие](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/make-receive-phone-calls-python-bottle-twilio-voice.html)

пример исходящего звонка через Twilio:

```
# Загрузите вспомогательную библиотеку https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install

from twilio.rest import Client

# Ваш аккаунт Sid и Auth Token из twilio.com/console
account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
                         twiml='<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>',
                         to='+14155551212',
                         from_='+15017122661')

print(call.sid)
```

`twiml` - язык разметки Twilio, который просто говорит о том, что это XML- документ со специальными тегами, определенными Twilio, чтобы помочь вам создавать ваши SMS и голосовые приложения.

[источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1128438/234134)

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что я хотел узнать